# Speculative assumptions about ISS end of life vs. physical limitations

Tags: iss, in-space-repairs

Is it possible to modernize ISS, replace parts one by one and it will still work, or is there a set of components which can't be replaced and will therefore come to a non-extendible "hard" end of life due to physics despite of any plans?

Comment: Is pimping a common technical term in the space industry? Extravagant decoration seems more, y'know, _extravagant_ when you have to load it all onto a rocket and fly it into orbit first.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I was ironical sorry

Comment: Given what constraints? With unlimited money and time anything could be replaced.

Comment: @OrganicMarble so could you safely split up ISS safely in two sub stations and replace a part in the middle? then the answer to this question is probably yes.

Comment: You probably could split it like that, possibly using the robotic arm and possibly some extra support structures. Replacing the seals embedded into the modules' berthing ports could be a nearly impossible procedure though.

Comment: Agree w @SF. if you also include EVA to work on all the connections.

Comment: Personally, I believe the wisest way to refurbish ISS would be the Theseus Boat approach. Replace it whole, module by module, migrating equipment that's "still good for a long time", and ditching shells of old modules.

Comment: @SF. also for that, we possibly have some time window to start with before some parts "overdue" and jeopardize the whole repair mission, or?

Comment: If you’re ultimately going to replace the whole thing, it *might* be better to design a whole new station incorporating lessons learned rather than to do a Station Of Theseus that requires compromises for compatibility. (Or it might not!)

Comment: @RussellBorogove Dumb structural parts like the trusses are going to be good for another 300 years. There's a lot that can be carried over. Of course replacing the modules with "new, better" is an option, but having an option to fall back to old stuff already in place in case new fails is always welcome. Also, would be a pity to lose the sizeable stockpile of water they apparently have in Zvezda.

Comment: Most of the modules can be replaced fairly "easily" (for a fairly broad definition of the term), except for the US lab, which has the structural connection of the module stack to the truss.